# "Свидетельствуют данные сайта" или "свидетельствуют данные на сайте"?

Tags: склонение, лексика

Здравствуйте, рассудите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "Свидетельствуют данные сайта" или "Свидетельствуют данные на сайте"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта возможны. Научная речь тяготеет к первому варианту.

Правда в некоторых контекстах между вариантами можно усмотреть некоторую разницу:
"Свидетельствуют данные на сайте" - данные выложены на сайте, но авторство (или копирайты) принадлежит не сайту. "Свидетельствуют данные сайта" такой смысловой нагрузки не несет. Но, повторюсь, это различие не всегда и не всеми просматривается.

> Речь идет об информации на сайте нашей (украинской) Центральной избирательной комиссии.

Это несколько меняет дело и упрощает выбор . В подобных случаях это данные ЦИК, а не сайта ЦИК, поэтому я за вариант "данные на сайте ЦИК".

Comment: Соглашусь, тоже хотел подчеркнуть возможность небольшой разницы в смысле(-ах)

Answer (score 1):

"Свидетельствуют данные сайта" - такая фраза уместна, если речь идет о множественности фактов, свидетельств, то есть о том, что на этом сайте опубликовано немало свидетельств, подтверждающих данное утверждение. Возможно, этот сайт вообще занимается данной проблемой.
"Свидетельствуют данные на сайте" - речь идет о тех конкретных данных, которые были опубликованы на этом сайте в какой-то момент или период. Эти данные могут не вписываться в проблематику данного сайта, но просто однажды опубликованы на нем.

Comment: Если написано "Данные Иванова свидетельствуют" - это к какой из двух случаев? А если "статьи Иванова"?  
Сайт в данно случае - такое же авторское "лицо".

Comment: Речь идет об информации на сайте нашей (украинской) Центральной избирательной комиссии.

Comment: ОК, но и пример с Ивановым был совершенно абстрактный, касался только не совсем понятного мне разделения на два случая, между которыми я не усматривал внятной разницы.
Касательео ЦИК - дополнил ответ.